# Run Flutter Desktop(Windows) debug with administrator rights

Tags: flutter, flutter-desktop, flutter-windows

I have an app Flutter (Windows 11) that makes changes to the registry (regedit) and for that it needs administrator permissions. How do I grant these permissions to debug mode window?

Comment: maybe start your IDE with admin rights?

Comment: Does not work. But when I go to the debug folder and run it as administrator, the .exe works, but I lose the debug, because this way it is not connected directly to vscode.

Comment: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/devtools/cli try running the debugger from an elevated powershell

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: Open Powershell as administrator, navigate to project folder and run flutter via:
flutter run -d windows